# Functional test vs functional testing terminology issues

Tags: testing, documentation, terminology, functional-testing

I have been trying to understand these but every article, wiki etc. says something else. My understanding is that:
**Functional test** means testing of a new functionality in isolation and against docs. Or maybe also exploratory testing?
**Funcional testing** means validating the application as a whole against specifications only from functional point of view.

And from book, functional testing is said to be a part of **System testing** when the whole app is tested and checked against Functinal Requirements or design documents.

Could anyone experienced in this field make it clear for me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Functional testing* is a *type* of testing, whereas *system testing* defines the *scope* of the test. The two are orthogonal concepts, though functional tests are usually performed on the system as a whole (hence the confusion in some people's minds).

**Functional test** - a test for a single function of the system

**Functional testing** - perfoming functional tests

Functional tests can be performed on any part of the system - e.g. individual classes or clusters of classes, sub-systems - or the system as a whole.

**System testing** - performing tests on the system as a whole, as opposed to a unit or module. These might be functional tests, usability tests, exploratory tests etc.

Also note that the distinction between tests and requirements documentation is blurred with frameworks such as [Concordion](http://www.concordion.org) allowing documentation to define and perform functional tests.

Comment: Thank you. But could you please comment on Wiki quote of Cam Kaner (that system testing differs from functional)?  functional testing "verif[ies] a program by checking it against ... design document(s) or specification(s)", while system testing "validate[s] a program by checking it against the published user or system requirements"

Comment: In my view Cem is mixing two concepts - scope of test and type of test. The vocabulary in the testing arena is overloaded. Making a distinction between requirements (goals) and designs (solutions) tends to be easy to say, but much harder to do in practice. Most requirements documents contain significant amounts of design and vice versa.

Comment: Take a look [at this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Software_Testing) and you can see that System Testing is classified as a "test level" (I prefer to call it scope because level implies hierarchy, which is not always appropriate).